# Change Flash version from non-debug to debug

Tags: flash

I have flash installed on my mac 10.6.7 and it's version is 11.1.102.55 (Non-debug).
How do i convert it into debug.
please help me.

Answer (score 4):

download and install the debugger version.
you'll get it here. http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html.

Also, you might want to have a look into http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/403/kb403009.html

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell if you are being sarcastic.  This is the correct answer, though, unless you are trying to have two versions running and choose between them?

Comment: Yeah, hard to tell if its a native vs non-native language difference or actually being sarcastic. But I too can vouch that you can't turn a "non" debug into debug, its actually two separate runtimes.

Comment: I'd bet on "lost in translation", too. ;)  +1 for the right answer.